# openpyxl - Possibility of graphing data points on scatter chart instead of a line? Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, logic, openpyxl

Basically, I am trying to graph a scatter plot however I just want to have the actual data points on the graph, NOT the whole line.

I've attempted at reading the documentation, but am fairly new to coding and have a hard time understanding what each means.

```
chart = ScatterChart(scatterStyle='marker')
    <br/> chart.title = '7.62 m Spacing'
    <br/> chart.style = 13
```

Some of the characteristics of the line are provided. I'm just getting a line, obviously.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html here is an example with just the points

Comment: I believe that only puts triangles in place of a line, and doesn't actually place the triangles on the actual points/coordinates of the graph. @Joe Let me know if I'm wrong.